# Scifi movie where souls are used as experimental weapons of war

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is an older science fiction movie about our military going to Germany or Russia and finding experiments on humans souls using them for war.

Our military makes a light beam so they can see them because they are invisible.

When the invisible beings touch them they freeze to death and die instantly.

The abandoned compound that houses all the souls is breaking and they all are escaping. American military is trying to save Earth from these killing human souls

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outpost_(2008_film)? There's a bunch of WWII bunker horror scifi films out there.

Comment: This surprisingly sounds like an average Supernatural episode :D

Answer (score 18):

***[Spectral](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106651/)*** (2016) seems to fit your description, although it's not what I'd call an 'older' movie.

From IMDB:

> A sci-fi/thriller story centered on a special-ops team that is dispatched to fight supernatural beings.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral):

> **DARPA researcher Dr. Mark Clyne flies to Moldova from Virginia, the current deployment location of the US military in the ongoing Moldovan War,** to be consulted on one of his creations, a line of hyperspectral imaging goggles that have been issued to troops there. After arriving at a US military airbase on the outskirts of Chișinău, **he meets with US Army General Orland and CIA officer Fran Madison. They show him footage captured by the troops' goggles of a mysterious, translucent, humanoid apparition that kills almost instantaneously.**
>
> [...]
>
> **Clyne modifies the hyperspectral camera into a large searchlight, which enables the group to see the apparitions without the need for goggles.**
>
> [...]
>
> Thinking over what he learned from the young girl they have rescued, **Clyne deduces the apparitions are likely man-made and are made of Bose-Einstein condensate, which explains their ability to move through walls, freeze people to death,** and the inability to pass through iron shavings and ceramic materials (hence their inability to penetrate ceramic tank armor and Comstock's hiding place under the bath tub).
>
> [...]
>
> While the soldiers mount an offensive distraction on the roof of the plant, Clyne and Madison descend down to a recently overrun laboratory inside. They deduce that **scientists, working in weapons research for the former regime, were scanning humans on a molecular level and using advanced 3D printing to replicate them in condensate form.**

Comment: YES OMG THATS IT !!!!!

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I’ve spent most of my day trying to figure this out. Your amazing and THANK YOU!! I was losing my mind ha ha❤️❤️❤️

Comment: @LogicDictates - OP tricked me because I couldn't believe that they were referring to a 2016/2017 film as "older"

Comment: @Valorum - It's not what I'd call an 'older' film either, but I've grown accustomed to story-ID answers occasionally being much newer than OP's descriptions seem to suggest. Also, the plot summary on Wikipedia seemed too perfect a match for this not to be worth a punt as an answer.

Comment: @Krista G - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the movie [spectral](https://www.google.com/search?q=spectral+movie).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer has already been suggested, and that answer includes a number of details about the movie to indicate how it matches.  In contrast, your answer just has a single link that's not clear how useful it is.  You shouldn't post duplicate answers without adding substantial additional content, and shouldn't post answers that basically consist of a link.